# Maternity pay in Sweden for a non-EU citizen with a temporary residence permit

Tags: resident-permit, sweden

I am interested what are my rights to be paid maternity pay after my 1-year residence permit for work in Sweden expires? Specifically, I am due to give birth approximately 7 weeks after my 12-month job contract ends. My residence permit for work in Sweden simultaneously expires with the end of my contract.

Would I need to have a (new) valid residence permit for the maternity benefit to be paid, that is: apply for extension to look for work? (although I would be preparing to give birth, not realistically able to look for work much)

I have a Swedish personal number and access to public healthcare.

I am a non-EU citizen, with the Settled Status in the UK (through my spouse who is an EU national). For tax purposes, my spouse is a resident in the UK, where he is employed. So, he didn't relocate to Sweden, although he moved with me physically.

Comment: It seems you would need a new valid residence permit to stay in Sweden anyway. Your status may or may not be checked when applying for unemployment or maternity benefits (many countries are doing this now) but that seems a bigger problem in general.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Relaxed . I thought so, too. I will definitely apply for the new permit to seek work. Swedish Migration Agency says it can take a year before it is granted. Thus, my anxiety over what are my rights while I am awaiting their decision.